# iPhone: Drawing on a UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton, drawing

This tutorial shows how to draw on a graphics context for the view using Quartz 2D:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iPhone_Graphics_Drawing_Tutorial_using_Quartz_2D

But I want to draw on a UIButton, not on a view. How can I do that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Draw on UIView . Add the view as subview to your UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

A button IS a UIView. It inherits from UIControl, which inherits from UIView.

So buttons have a drawRect method.

So you can do everything described in the article you linked on a button.

However, buttons are set up to do a lot of things for you, and overriding the drawRect method could make those things not work correctly.

Buttons normally draw a title and a rounded rectangle frame. You can turn that off by setting the button's type to custom.

Custom buttons will draw an image if you install one.

Buttons normally also either draw a highlight over their image, or have a second image to use for the highlighted state. If you want to implement drawRect, you'll need to handle drawing the highlighted state yourself.

In general, you want to avoid using drawRect and use some other technique to get the content you want into your views.

What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to draw a line or a circle on a UIButton by clicking another Button. Thanks for help